# Measure current on a constant current source

Tags: current, voltage-measurement, voltage-divider

I need to measure current on a constant current source(LM317), because I am using a 3v3 chip I also need a voltage divider to read it. Will this circuit work Or will it wreak havoc trying to increase voltage to drive current over the voltage dividers?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM6O80.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why do you need to measure the current? Do you not trust your current source to work as advertised? In any case, the LM317 circuit already has a resistor in it that you can measure across, and the delta voltage there will be 1.25V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the load is connected, it'll work, but if the load or the shunt becomes disconnected or burns out, expect it to fail as you described (the voltage you see depends on the voltage available to the current source : if that's only 12V, the ADC inputs have enough protection to survive).

However, it won't be very accurate. Unless you pay a lot for extremely high precision resistors, errors (say about 1% of 150ma * 20 ohms, 30mv ) in the voltage dividers will be larger in magnitude than the voltages you are measuring across that 10mohm (0.01 * 156ma=1.5mv) shunt.

A safer and more accurate version would put the current shunt on the earth side of the load and eliminate the dividers. You lose the inaccuracy of the dividers, and whether the load goes open or short circuit the ADC is still safe. You probably need to increase the shunt to 1 ohm, or add amplification, to get any accuracy though.

Answer (score 4):

With 156 mA through 19.01 Ohms (load + shunt), the maximum voltage will be **2.966 Volts**, which should not be a problem for typical 3.3 Volt microcontrollers.

Therefore the voltage dividers may be unnecessary for reading the voltage at either side of that shunt.

Further, the Voltage developed across the 10 milliOhm shunt will be a mere **1.56 milliVolts**. At approximately 3.22 mV per consecutive ADC reading on the MCU (`3.3 Volts full-scale / 1024`, assuming 10 bit Atmel MCU ADC) there will not be much to be read between the high and low side of that shunt.

Adding the voltage divider does nothing useful as far as I can see, and it definitely will reduce the voltage to the ADC, challenging it to read anything useful.

Comment: The advantage of the voltage divider is when the shunt fails the current through the AVR's input will be limited. But the same effect can be accomplished with a series resistor to the controller's input, without sacrificing accuracy.

Comment: @jippie Agreed - even if the shunt fails open, a limiting resistor will prevent fireworks on the ADC pin.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you have shown theoretically works but practically it has difficulties in matching the 4 x 30k resistors to get decent accuracy. I'm not saying it shouldn't be considered but an alternative is this: -

Place the 10milli-ohm resistor in the ground lead of the 19 ohm load. Then you can directly measure the voltage developed across it into an ADC input. There are still complications with this but they are less than with high-side measurement you propose.

The complications are keeping the ground potential at a really decent constant level around the load sense resistor. I'd also consider using a load sense resistor that is as big as you could make it.

On your circuit, at 156mA, the voltage across 10 milli-ohms would be 1.56 milli-volts and then your circuit attenuates that by two with the 30k resistors!! It's very unlikely you'll get a meaningful voltage that represents load current AND even with my suggestion there are going to be resolution problems with the in-built ADCs on MCUs.

I'd definitely want to make it maybe 0.1 ohms and also I'd consider an amplifier BUT I don't know how this would fit in with your application?

Of course, if the 19 ohm load is constant then you can measure the voltage across it either directly (if the voltage is within the ADC range) or via a potential divider.